# Compress and Minify multiples javascript files into one, with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to concatenate, minify multiples javascript files into one, with webpack.

So my question can this be done with webpack? and How?

I tried a lot of ways, but couldn't get it to work as what I wanted.

Best I show examples.

3 javascript files.

**app.js**

```
var fnA = function () {
    console.log('fnA')
}
```

**global.js**

```
fnA();
```

**main.js**

```
require('./app.js');
require('./global.js');
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : [
        './app/main.js'
    ],
    output : {
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename : 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(
        {
            minimize: true,
            compress: false,
            mangle: {
                 keep_fnames: true
            },
            bare_returns : true
        }),
    ]
};
```

I'm expecting that **global.js** is able to call to any function in **app.js**. 
Probably this can be done with grunt, but I thought webpack can do this too.

Worry that I'm heading to a total wrong direction. Google around, but can't seem to find any solution, tried with other plugin suc as chunk, which doesn't helps.

Any advices are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pasted the correct code you probably got typos. The Name of the function in app.js is `fnA()` and not `fn()`, so your call in global.js is probably wrong. Furthermore your function is only accessable in app.js so you need to export it with `module.exports`.

Comment: typo, edited. So meaning in order for `global.js` to access the function, I need to `module.exports` from `app.js`?

Answer (score 1):

I put together something simple but you need babel.

https://github.com/vpanjganj/simple-webpack-sample

This is your webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [ "./app/main.js" ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: [ { loader: 'babel-loader' } ], exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ]
};
```

here your 2 modules:

First module, `moduleOne.js`:

```
export default function sayHello() {
   console.log('hello')
}
```

`moduleTwo.js` file:

```
export default function sayBye() {
   console.log('bye')
}
```

and your `main.js` file:

```
import sayHello from './moduleOne'
import sayBye from './moduleTwo'

const myApp = ()=>{
   sayHello();
   sayBye()
};

myApp();
```

The command to build:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack  --color --display-error-details --config ./webpack.js"
```